# How to programmatically access the Eclipse Help System?

Tags: java, html, eclipse, plugins, rcp

Background:
I have a plugin which should give out links to helpfiles of other, currently installed, eclipse plugins.

At first I thought that I include those html files in my plugin, but I couldn't open them unless I copy them into the current workspace of the user. Since this is not an option, the most elegant way would be to use the eclipse-built-in help system.

So I need to access the eclipse help system programmatically to include the files into my code.

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Edit: I guess I missed a central point: I generate an HTML-File, in which the links to the help system should be embedded.

When I open the helpfile to a given plugin, there is a link like this at the bottom:

http://127.0.0.1:11925/help/topic/plugin/help/html/maintopic.html?cp=5_1_2

The problem is: I can't access this document but I would need to.

Comment: The 'User Assistance Support' section of the 'Platform Plug-in Developer Guide' in the Eclipse Help covers this.

Comment: thank you, I read it before but my problem is not covered by this.

Comment: I don't think the help system supports accessing its files from HTML files which are not part of the help system.

Answer (score 2):

From the  Eclipse Platform API Specification, implement the `IWorkbenchHelpSystem interface` and call the `displayHelp()` method without an argument to programmatically open the Help window, or call the `displayHelp()` method with the context ID string as the single argument to programmatically open context-sensitive help for a specific context ID. Read the API for further information.